# Just installed ubuntu on an acer latop and now the touchpad wont work. How do i fix this?

Tags: touchpad

As the title says, i just installed ubuntu via a flash drive and now the curoer remains stationary on my screen. It wont click or move. How do i fix this?
[Picture of desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYiFd.jpg)

Comment: Instead of posting desktop picture, please update your question with Ubuntu version, output of `xinput`, `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i touchpad`.

Comment: Which Asus (`sudo dmidecode --type 1`)?  Which Ubuntu (`lsb_release -a`)?

Answer (score 0):

When booting get into the BIOS settings (F2) and set touchpad mode on "basic" instead of "advanced" (it's in a different part of the BIOS settings depending on the laptop, as far as I know). Then go to "exit" and choose "exit and save changes". Then get into Ubuntu (the touchpad will now work but not perfectly) and install the package "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" (from a package manager or from the terminal with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`). After that, the touchpad will work perfectly on Ubuntu.

If you have dual boot, you will have to set it on "advanced" again in order to have it work perfectly on Windows, and on "basic" in order to have it work at all on Ubuntu. The package "xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" will give you on Ubuntu all the advanced functions that the "advanced" mode gives you on Windows (two fingers etc.)

Comment: Last versions of Ubuntu move to libinput ( `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`) instead of synaptics.

Comment: On my Acer laptop with Kubuntu 17.10 it doesn't work unless I have both synaptics and libinput installed

Comment: Might be related to [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292920/209677). You don't have libinput on the output of `xinput list-props 11` where 11 is the device id? You can find the device id with `xinput`.

Comment: I don't want to risk to make a mess again. It works and I will keep it this way.

Comment: JFTR, listing properties of a device don't  brake things.

Comment: I can list them but I don't want to make changes. If I don't have a USB mouse plugged in, when I write `xinput list-props 11` it says `unable to find device 11`. When I write `xinput`, the ID of the synaptics touchpad is 14. Only the USB mouse is 11 when I plug it in